# Handling two almost identical tables as one model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm working on creating some models for the wikimedia databases located on wikimedia labs, and due to technical issues, there are two tables for revisions.

One table `revision` contains all revisions, but lacks a index on username due to it's a view made up of expression to blank usernames for some revisions.

The other table `revision_userindex` has the index, but instead it lacks the revisions that where affected by the blanking.

Other than that, they are identical, and I would want to be able to use it as one single model instead of passing on the low level detail of the index to the user.

Currently I have following code:

```
class Revision < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :revision_userindex # or :revision
  self.primary_key = :rev_id

  has_many :externallinks, :class_name => 'Externallink', :foreign_key => :el_from    
  has_many :iwlinks, :class_name => 'Iwlink', :foreign_key => :iwl_from    
  has_many :langlinks, :class_name => 'Langlink', :foreign_key => :ll_from    
  has_many :pagelinks, :class_name => 'Pagelink', :foreign_key => :pl_from    
  has_many :recentchanges, :class_name => 'Recentchange', :foreign_key => :rc_this_oldid    
  belongs_to :page, :class_name => 'Page', :foreign_key => :rev_page    
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :rev_user    
  has_many :templatelinks, :class_name => 'Templatelink', :foreign_key => :tl_from    
  has_many :texts, :class_name => 'Text', :foreign_key => :old_id    
end
```

But I don't know of any way to dynamically set `self.table_name` depending on whenever a user is specified in the context or not. i.e.

```
Revision.find_by_page("page")
Revision.find(nnn)
Revision.where(...) # where the query doesn't link to the user table
@page.revisions
# etc...
```

should use the `revision` table, and

```
Revision.find_by_user("user")
@user.revisions
```

should use the `revision_userindex` table

If this where possible to accomplish without reimplementing half of AR, I would be happy to know.

The primary_key is the same for both tables.

For reference, here is the definition if the tables:

First for revision:

```mysql
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`viewmaster`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `revision` AS
SELECT `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_id` AS `rev_id`,
       `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_page` AS `rev_page`,
       if((`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` & 1),NULL,`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_text_id`) AS `rev_text_id`,
       if((`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` & 2),NULL,`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_comment`) AS `rev_comment`,
       if((`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` & 4),NULL,`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_user`) AS `rev_user`,
       if((`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` & 4),NULL,`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_user_text`) AS `rev_user_text`,
       `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_timestamp` AS `rev_timestamp`,
       `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_minor_edit` AS `rev_minor_edit`,
       `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` AS `rev_deleted`,
       if((`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` & 1),NULL,`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_len`) AS `rev_len`,
       `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_parent_id` AS `rev_parent_id`,
       if((`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` & 1),NULL,`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_sha1`) AS `rev_sha1`
FROM `enwiki`.`revision`
```

And for revision_userindex:

```mysql
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`viewmaster`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `revision_userindex` AS
SELECT `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_id` AS `rev_id`,
       `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_page` AS `rev_page`,
       if((`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` & 1),NULL,`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_text_id`) AS `rev_text_id`,
       if((`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` & 2),NULL,`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_comment`) AS `rev_comment`,
       `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_user` AS `rev_user`,
       `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_user_text` AS `rev_user_text`,
       `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_timestamp` AS `rev_timestamp`,
       `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_minor_edit` AS `rev_minor_edit`,
       `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` AS `rev_deleted`,
       if((`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` & 1),NULL,`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_len`) AS `rev_len`,
       `enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_parent_id` AS `rev_parent_id`,
       if((`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` & 1),NULL,`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_sha1`) AS `rev_sha1`
FROM `enwiki`.`revision`
WHERE ((`enwiki`.`revision`.`rev_deleted` & 4) = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put common logic / configuration in a mixin and then use two different models that include it. Something like this (untested, but you get the idea):

```
module RevisionCommon
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern

 included do

  has_many :externallinks, :class_name => 'Externallink', :foreign_key => :el_from    
  has_many :iwlinks, :class_name => 'Iwlink', :foreign_key => :iwl_from    
  has_many :langlinks, :class_name => 'Langlink', :foreign_key => :ll_from    
  has_many :pagelinks, :class_name => 'Pagelink', :foreign_key => :pl_from    
  has_many :recentchanges, :class_name => 'Recentchange', :foreign_key => :rc_this_oldid    
  belongs_to :page, :class_name => 'Page', :foreign_key => :rev_page    
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :rev_user    
  has_many :templatelinks, :class_name => 'Templatelink', :foreign_key => :tl_from    
  has_many :texts, :class_name => 'Text', :foreign_key => :old_id
 end

 module ClassMethods
  # if any
 end
end

class RevisionForPage < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :revision_userindex # or :revision
  self.primary_key = :rev_id

  include RevisionCommon
end

class RevisionForUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :revision_userindex # or :revision
  self.primary_key = :rev_user_id # or whatever
  include RevisionCommon
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require the controller to select which model to use depending on whenever a user is in context or not? Also, the primary_key will always be the same, it's only the table name that differs.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`revision` and `revision_userindex` are views, not tables. Just link your model to the `enwiki.revision` table directly.</strike>

*direct access not authorised*

[edit]

<strike>Since you do not have access to the underlying physical table, I would suggest creating an aggregating view on top of these two views, and link your model to this new view. The MySQL optimizer should be able to decide for you which version of the view to use.</strike>

```sql
CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE VIEW revision_superview AS
SELECT
    r.rev_id, r.rev_page,
    COALESCE(r.rev_user, ru.rev_user) AS rev_user,
    -- and so on
FROM revision AS r JOIN revision_user AS ru USING (rev_id)
```

*queries on the view do not use indexes*

[edit]

It was confirmed that [no index will be used](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50fbe/3) with the above workaround.

Perhaps your best option would be to ask your DBA to create another view that aggregates the data directly from the physical table. Tell him/her you already have access to this data. I will gladly write the view definition if s/he needs.

Comment: I don't have access to the table directly, only through the views (due to sensitive data that has to be masked).

Comment: If you want to have a chat with him, he Hans out on #wikimedia-labs on freenode as Coren

Comment: I don't think this would bring anything new to the table. I see two options here. Either, as you suggest, you switch table/view on the fly in your model based on the query, or you create a new view that presents the equivalent of `view1 JOIN view2`. I can't really tell why I dislike the first option - perhaps a bit too hackish to me, or maybe because I have no clue in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different tables and "computer" should choose which one to use at some point. There are 3 places where it can happen:

1. Your code: you create 2 ARs and, let's say, an IF statement chooses which one to use.
2. SQL code: IF statement in SP or view. However it is not possible to do in MySQL (as far as I know). - this would be my preferred option, if it could be possible.
3. SQL statement, then Query Optimiser will be choosing right table. There are several ways to sneak choice into SQL statement. It can be done via `JOIN` or `UNION ALL` or, maybe some other way. However in my opinion MySQL engine is not designed for such things. It's speciality is to work with rows fast. Making comparisons and adding layers of abstraction are addons, that have limited use.

I would suggest with creating 2 AR objects and choosing one of them. You can create AR class without specifying table name, and then 2 new AR objects will inherit all properties plus will define table name. My knowledge of Ruby is limited, so I apologise if this suggestion is not entirely correct.